# How to check specific radio buttons are present

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I need help with protractor code to check whether both radio buttons ( yes and no ) are present or not.

The HTML looks like this for yes and no radio buttons

#### For No radio button html code

```
<input required="required"
    class="ng-touched ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" 
    name="dangerousGood" id="dangerousGoodNo" data-ng-model="SLI.dangerous" 
    value="false" data-ng-required="true" 
    ng-change="updateCommodityType('N');isSrvLvlHazmat();errorMsgOnScreen.msg2 = false;" 
    type="radio">
```

#### For Yes Radio button Html code

```
<input required="required"
    class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" 
    name="dangerousGood" data-ng-model="SLI.dangerous"
    value="true" data-ng-required="true" 
    ng-change="updateCommodityType('Y');isSrvLvlHazmat();"
    type="radio">
```

Comment: <input required="required" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="dangerousGood" data-ng-model="SLI.dangerous" value="true" ng-change="updateCommodityType('Y');isSrvLvlHazmat();" data-ng-required="true" type="radio">

Comment: <input required="required" class="ng-touched ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" name="dangerousGood" id="dangerousGoodNo" data-ng-model="SLI.dangerous" value="false" data-ng-required="true" ng-change="updateCommodityType('N');isSrvLvlHazmat();errorMsgOnScreen.msg2 = false;" type="radio">

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question and indented the HTML with 4 spaces to make sure it gets formatted as intended. Please add the code you have tried with and where you got stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If it is the presence, and not visibility, you need to check, just use `element.all()` to find both inputs and check the [`count()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count):

```
var checkboxes = element.all(by.name("dangerousGood"));
expect(checkboxes.count()).toEqual(2);
```

You can also use the [`by.model()` locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model):

```
var checkboxes = element.all(by.model("SLI.dangerous"));
```

---

You can also find both checkboxes separately, assert the presence/visibility and check what button [is selected](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected) by default:

```
var yesRadioButton = $("input[name=dangerousGood]:not(#dangerousGoodNo)");
var noRadioButton = $("input#dangerousGoodNo");

expect(yesRadioButton.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(noRadioButton.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

expect(yesRadioButton.isSelected()).toBe(true);
expect(noRadioButton.isSelected()).toBe(false);
```

Comment: Can u please explain me what does this statement mean

Comment: var yesRadioButton = $("input[name=dangerousGood]:not(#dangerousGoodNo)");

Comment: i did not understand the second part that is  :not(#dangerousGoodNo)

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y it is a check for the matching element not having the `id="dangerousGoodNo"`.

Comment: Iam still getting the below message

Comment: Expected false to be true

Comment: I have still modified the code as shown below but still i am getting the error by while checking for the element is present or displayed

Comment: element.all(by.model('SLI.dangerous')).then(function(arrayOfElement){
     var No_Of_Hazmat_radio_buttons = arrayOfElement.length;
     console.log("No of Hazmat radio buttons webelements are  :"+No_Of_Hazmat_radio_buttons);

     for(i=0;i<arrayOfElement.length;i++){
                // console.log(" Hazmat option --------- :" +arrayOfElement[i].getAttribute(value));
    
      expect(arrayOfElement[i].isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

    } 
   
   });